# Recoded a variable with if_else and mutate function, however it creates more answers than should be possible

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, recode

A sample of my dataset:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYLAg.png

```
> str(df_nr_axspa)
'data.frame':   6522 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ asas_criteria    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 NA 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ new_york_criteria: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 NA 2 NA 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ nr_axspa         : num  0 0 NA 0 NA 0 1 2 0 0 ...
```

I wish to recode a variable which I want to call nr-axspa. This variable is a diagnosis, a subform of spondyloarthritis, which is a rheumatic disease. The diagnosis can be inferred based on the classification criteria of the ASAS and New York criteria.

If the patients has 1 in ASAS but 0 in New York, then he/she has nr-axspa, otherwise not (in that case it is r-axspa). I recoded everyone with nr-axspa to "1", everyone without nr-axspa to "0" and some that have ASAS 0 and New York 0 to "2". This is the code I used:

```
df_nr_axspa <- mutate(df, nr_axspa = if_else(asas_criteria == 0 & new_york_criteria == 0, 2, 
                                             if_else(asas_criteria == 1 & new_york_criteria == 0, 1, 0)))
```

Interestingly enough, when I look at summary(df_nr_axspa$nr_axspa) I find that there are 1596 patients with a diagnosis. However, I would have expected there to be only 1434 cases.

When I create a 2x2 table of ASAS criteria and New York criteria, it gives me these numbers:

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>New York</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ASAS</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>372</td>
<td>992</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So according to this table, there should be 20 patients without a diagnosis or group "2", 372 patients with diagnosis "1" or "nr-axspa" and 1042 patients with "0" or "r-axspa".

However, the newly coded variable has a frequency of 372 for "1", 20 for "2" but 1204 for "0". So the group "1" and group "2" have been classified correctly, but of group "0" we have suddendly a surplus of 162 patients with this diagnosis.

The code I used to determine the frequencies of the newly coded variable

```
describe(df_nr_ax_spa$nr_ax_spa)
```

So I am trying to figure out what the hell happened. When I look at the data manually, I can't seem to find any mistake in the way the new variable is coded. Does anyone have an explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if mutate + case_when would work for you?

```
df_nr_axspa <- df_nr_axspa %>%
  mutate(nr_axspa = case_when(
    asas_criteria = 0 & new_york_criteria == 0 ~ 2,
    asas_criteria = 1 & new_york_criteria == 0 ~ 1))
```

Maybe another answer can help you understand what went wrong with your other code. Maybe the NA values created problems; I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response & suggestion. I tried your code, but it gave me n = 415 only instead of the expected n = 1434. I added "new_york_criteria == 1 ~ 0" to the formula, but got now n = 1619.

You might be on the right track with the NA's. However, when I check manually, it appears that when ASAS is NA or New York is NA, it gives back in nr_axspa NA, as one would expect.

Comment: could you type dput(df_nr_axspa) into your console and copy and paste the result into your question. The output will look like structure(list(etc. This allows us to use your df on our local machines - the screenshot is not super helpful for recreating and testing on our end

Comment: Hi Hachiko, I will edit the question and add the structure of the database.
When I put dput then I just get a long list of the data and I am not sure if I am allowed to share it even without patient ID.

Answer (score 0):

There could easily be a problem with using having your criteria as factors with numbers as names. You can see in your "str" output that the values from the individuals do not match the levels. Change your if_else to have quotes around the numbers, ie

```
df_nr_axspa <- mutate(df, nr_axspa = if_else(asas_criteria == "0" & new_york_criteria == "0", 2, 
                                             if_else(asas_criteria == "1" & new_york_criteria == "0", 1, 0)))
```

Not sure if this is the issue.

I don't ever recommend factors with numbers as names - can cause great confusion!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly, this solution did not work for me. Still got the same results!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem. When I checked the total amount of patients with New York criteria = 1, it came back to 1204. It dawned on me that the formula is working perfectly, but my calculation of total patients that should have "r-axspa" and therefore New York criteria = 1, was simply wrong. So the cross-table only shows the patients with both ASAS & New York criteria, but does not include patients with New York criteria = 1 but a missing ASAS.

I managed to find this solution, because I split the if_else function into 3 parts and put them in a different vector (x1,x2,x3) to see where the mistake occurs.